# P:contextMenu is not rendering inside P:layout component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have to write P:contextMenu inside P:layout tag
The ContextMenu in first P:layout is not rendering.
My page is as follows:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
  <h:body>
 <h:form id="statementsOfAccountForm">
        <p:layout id="playout" style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100"
                minSize="40" maxSize="200" collapsible="true">
    <h:form id="statementsOfAccountLeftForm">
                <p:contextMenu>
                    <p:menuitem value="Account Summary" 
                         />
                    <p:menuitem value="Mini Statement" 
                         />

                </p:contextMenu>
  </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerPage" collapsible="true">
                 <h:form id="statementsOfAccountCenterForm">
        <div align="center">hi</div>
      </h:form>
        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
```

Here Is my code, 
!I see output as follows : Context Menu is not displayed in proper format. Page only displays plain links. What is wrong ?Please help.see the screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYAv7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `update` attribute likely cannot find a component with the id of `centerPage` and thus is not rendering.

Temporarily remove the update attribute from the menuItem's and then evaluate the client source for the generated client id of the components within the `centerPage` layoutUnit that you would like to update.  You can then refer to these specifically by clientId.

One problem however is that the `layoutUnit` component likely does not generate a client side component for you to reference, so you will probably have to reference a component within this layoutUnit directly.

```
...
<p:menuitem value="Account Summary" update=":statementsOfAccountForm:centerPageGroup"
... 


<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerPage" collapsible="true">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="centerPageGroup"><ui:include 
        src="#{helloBean.pageName}.xhtml" /></h:panelGroup> 
</p:layoutUnit>
```

This is an example of how you can reference an id specifically using the update attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but actually my problem is, I am not able to see the context menu at all. I have updated the question to add up more clarity.

Comment: @amruta as maple_shaft has said, the context menu probably isn't rendering, temporary remove the ` update="centerPage"`and follow maple_shaft's directions.

Comment: Hi, yes I removed the update attribute and deployed but still I could not see the menu component on the page. Also, This page is included in some other page. When I am writing the menu component in the main page it is displaying properly but when I am writing it in <ui:composition> the menu is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example (removed the references to the backing beans though) and it works as expected:

```
<h:form id="statementsOfAccountForm">
    <p:layout id="playout" style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;">
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100"
            minSize="40" maxSize="200" collapsible="true">
            <p:contextMenu>
                <p:menuitem value="Account Summary" update="centerPage" />
                <p:menuitem value="Mini Statement" update="centerPage" />
            </p:contextMenu>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerPage" collapsible="true">
            <div align="center">
            </div>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:form>
```

Result:

[image: Result of context menu]

I suggest you try exactly the same thing as I did. After verifying that this works, add more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is residing within a single h:form. You should actually have a h:form within each layout unit. So try the following:

```
<p:layout id="playout" style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100"
        minSize="40" maxSize="200" collapsible="true">
        <h:form id="statementsOfAccountLeftForm">
            <p:contextMenu>
                <p:menuitem value="Account Summary" update="centerPage"
                    actionListener="#{helloBean.changeCenterPage('accountSummary')}" />
                <p:menuitem value="Mini Statement" update="centerPage"
                    actionListener="#{helloBean.changeCenterPage('miniStatement')}" />

            </p:contextMenu>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerPage" collapsible="true">
        <h:form id="statementsOfAccountCenterForm">
            <div align="center"><ui:include
                src="#{helloBean.pageName}.xhtml" /></div>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I cannot see how this relates to the problem of the OP. It doesn't matter if the OP uses one or several forms. I agree however that it is better practice to have only forms around things that belong in a form.

Comment: When I added form tag enclosing the contextMenu Tag Tags are displayed like plain links.I have modified the question to show the screen shot. Please check

Comment: For clarification, do those links in your screen shot appear when the page renders or is that what the context menu looks like when you right click on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

[Primefaces 3.3 User's Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf), page 245, says:

> When working with forms and full page layout, avoid using a form that
>   contains layoutunits as generated dom may not be the same. So
>   following is invalid.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <h:form>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100">
            <h:outputText value="Left Pane" />
        </p:layoutUnit> 
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:outputText value="Right Pane" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </h:form>
</p:layout>
```

> A layout unit must have it’s own form instead, also avoid trying to
>   update layout units because of same reason, update it’s content
>   instead.

Primefaces menus have a little problem when used inside layoutUnits. To overcome [this issue](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14013) you can use this CSS snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-layout-unit-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.ui-layout .ui-layout-noscroll div.ui-layout-bd {
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>
```

or you can try [another approach](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14801) if the above doesn't work:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-layout-west {
    z-index:20 !important;
    overflow:visible;
}

.ui-layout-west .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:visible;
}
</style>
```